# Set Theory proof. Natural Numbers

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-writing

Let $\mathbb{N}$ be the set of natural numbers.

Show that $$\mathbb{N} \leq \mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N}$$

I know this is true but I don't know how to show it.

Please help!

Comment: What do you mean by $\Bbb N\leqslant\Bbb N\times \Bbb N$?

Comment: In terms of cardinality yes. It means "No larger than".

Comment: Technically, you presumably want it to mean "(cardinality) smaller or equal than".

Comment: Why do you *know* this is true? And what is the *definition* of $\leq$, not your "intuitive understanding of 'No larger than'"?

Comment: I don't know how to make the symbol, its not less than or equal too. The symbol does mean "No larger than".

Comment: To get less than or equal, you use \le between dollar signs to get $\le$  If you want the slanted one it is \leslant.  You can right click on any MathJax and select Show Math As ->TeX commands to see how it was done.

Comment: Are you looking for $\not>$, created by `\not >`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are describing [Cantor pairing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pairing_function#Derivation). Construct an infinite table of (x, y),  $x \in \mathbb{N}, y \in \mathbb{N}$. The natural numbers have cardinality $\aleph_0$, and so does the set of (x, y) pairs. Why? Because one can construct a 1-to-1 mapping between them, with $45^{\circ}$ boustrophedon traversal of indices starting with: (1, 1), (1, 2), (2, 1), (3, 1), (2, 2).... He used it to show the rationals ($\frac{x}{y}$) have the same cardinality as the natural numbers.

Comment: Wait, are you claiming that $\Bbb{N\times N}$ is uncountable? Because that's just plain wrong.

Comment: Asaf, I don't understand your remark. Quoting the cited reference: A set has cardinality $\aleph_{0}$ if and only if it is countably infinite, that is, there is a bijection (one-to-one correspondence) between it and the natural numbers. I gave Cantor's 1-to-1 correspondence between OP's $\mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N}$, and the countable set $\mathbb{N}$.

Answer (score 0):

You have an injection from $\Bbb N$ into $\Bbb {N \times N}$ by $n \to (n,1)$.  That is all you need to show less than or equal to.  More interesting, and you can find it on this site, is to show they are equal.